# ValueError when trying to count values in list with dataframe inside

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a function with takes three arguments. I am trying to ensure that only two inputs have values which are not none. A dataframe will be passed as the argument.

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'B': [3,4]})

def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    missing_inputs = [a, b, c].count(None)
    if missing_inputs < 1:
        print('Too many')
    elif missing_inputs > 1:
        print('Not enough')
    else:
        print('Just right')

foo(a=df_a, b=df_b)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What's the correct way to make this function work with datafrme inputs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether each is a DataFrame and count the False values instead:

```
missing_inputs = sum(not isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) for x in [a,b,c])
```

Or as pointed out, you can do this:

```
missing_inputs = sum(x is None for x in [a,b,c])
```

or more generally:

```
missing_inputs = sum(x is None for x in locals().values())
```

Comment: `missing_inputs = sum([a is None, b is None, c is None])` more generally addresses the question. And reads better.

Comment: I would say in that case you want to do `missing_inputs = sum(x is None for x in [a,b,c])` (see my edit)